# Get the rows with specific range (not datetime) in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I would like to ask for your help on how to get the rows with specific range that are not based on datetime using MySQL query. My sample data show below:

```
datetime            action      
2017-05-01 01:02:32 Login       
2017-05-01 02:02:32 Task 1      
2017-05-01 01:32:32 Task 2      
2017-05-01 02:02:32 Logout      
2017-05-01 03:30:32 Login       
2017-05-02 01:02:32 Task 3      
2017-05-02 02:02:32 Task 4      
2017-05-02 03:02:32 Logout
```

So on that records I would like to get only the latest records with having the range of action that has a Login value until the Logout value. So my result should be like this:

```
datetime            action      
2017-05-01 03:30:32 Login       
2017-05-02 01:02:32 Task 3      
2017-05-02 02:02:32 Task 4      
2017-05-02 03:02:32 Logout
```

Any idea how? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You need add the time or something to order the rows. Right now you can't know if Task1 become before or after Login.

Comment: ahh yes, assuming the date is datetime.

Comment: Well include the time, right now you have two login on the same date. So you cant split those. And there is no way to generate your desire output

Comment: Even an Auto Incremented ID column could probably help.

Comment: I have edited the table, of course there is primary id (incremented) on the table.

Comment: There's no 'of course' about it

Comment: You can easily have a table without an ID column, so it was not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT datetime, action 
FROM table 
WHERE datetime >= (
    SELECT datetime 
    FROM table 
    WHERE action="Login" 
    ORDER BY datetime DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY datetime ASC
```